# how to get the selected/ active mat expansion panel name using Typescript

Tags: typescript, angular-material, angular7

I have used mat-expansion panel. Dynmically binded the panel title name. When user clicks the mat-list item i have to get the respective panel name and i need to display the name in some other div. Help me to get the active/selected mat-expansion-panel name in typescript.

```
<mat-accordion>
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let templateList of LeftpaneTableDetails first as isFirst" [expanded]="isFirst">
        <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <mat-panel-title>
                {{templateList.strTemplateName}}
            </mat-panel-title>
            <mat-panel-description>
            </mat-panel-description>
        </mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-list>
            <mat-list-item class="cursor-pointer table-name-list" *ngFor="let table of templateList.tableList" [attr.data-message-tableId]="table.intTableId" (click)="populateTableDetails($event, table.intTableId, table.strTableLabelName, templateList.strTemplateName)">{{table.strTableLabelName}}</mat-list-item>
        </mat-list>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component.ts, add `@ViewChild` in order to get a reference to the `MatAccordion` directive. Then retrieve the expanded `MatExpansionPanelHeader` as shown below.

```
@ViewChild(MatAccordion) accordion: MatAccordion; 

...

getExpandedPanelHeader(): MatExpansionPanelHeader {
    return this.accordion._headers.find(h => h._isExpanded());
}
```

**UPDATE**

If the only purpose is to display the name (title) of the expanded `mat-expansion-panel` in a `div`, you could use an `afterExpand` event handler. Each time a `mat-expansion-panel` is expanded, you would store it's title in the component class (i.e. in `selectedTitle`) and could use that value inside your `div`.

See following [**StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-expansion-panel-nv6vyc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)